# What is the best way to distribute static assets via NPM package?

Tags: npm, webpack, sass

I am working on an NPM package (an internal design library) which distributes CSS, SASS mixins and static assets to other projects.

A problem which I am facing is that my host application's Webpack build is failing when I try to include a SASS mixin coming from my NPM package which references a static asset. This is happening because Webpack tries to resolve all urls relative to the output Webpack file (read more [here](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#problems-with-url)). This works well when I am building the NPM package but is not when I am building the host application.

I have setup a repo where the problem could be easily reproduced - https://github.com/dobrinov/playground/tree/main/webpack/npm-distribute-assets

The solutions which I have found for this problems are:

#### Inline your assets in the distributed CSS and SASS files

This is the approach which Twitter Bootstrap 5 uses for distributing SVGs.

#### URL rewriting

This could be achieved by the [resolve-url-loader](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader) Webpack loader which will rewrite urls to be relative to the file that contain them and not to the Webpack output file.

#### SASS variables

This is something which Twitter Bootstrap did in its old SASS implementation. It is not ideal because in order to achieve it you have to use SASS `@import` (it puts variables in the global space) instead of `@use`, which is discouraged.

Does anyone have a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which works well for me. It couples my host application with Webpack but this is fine for my case. You can view an implementation of it in [the "solution" branch](https://github.com/dobrinov/playground/tree/solution) of my sample project.

## tl;dr;

I created a SASS variable holding the root path and placed it in a SCSS file. In development its value is `./`. When I am building the distributable version of the package I am [replacing](https://github.com/dobrinov/playground/blob/solution/webpack/npm-distribute-assets/distributable/webpack.config.js#L18) this [file](https://github.com/dobrinov/playground/blob/solution/webpack/npm-distribute-assets/distributable/src/scss/_assets-root.scss) with [another one](https://github.com/dobrinov/playground/blob/solution/webpack/npm-distribute-assets/distributable/src/scss/_production-assets-root.scss) which sets the variable value to `~distributable/dist/scss/`. The trick here is that when the `css-loader` tries to resolve the asset paths the `~` will make it look in the [resolve](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#url) paths and since there will be a `distributable` directory in `node_modules` this will work fine.

This will work fine only if:

1. You are using [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) in your host application
2. The `node_modules` directory is in [modules.resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve)
3. [webpackImporter](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#webpackimporter) is not turned off for `sass-loader`