# Webpack 5 - how to bundle assets from an npm module

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, node-modules, webpack-5

I have built an npm module. I am struggling to find a way to configure webpack 5 to include module-assets in an app that has the module as a dependency.

### Context

What I have is something like:

`myNpmModule`

```
dist/
    index.js
    assets/
        image.png
```

I use the module as follows

```
// project/app.jsx
import Component from 'myNpmModule'
return <Component />
```

In this example, `<Component />` renders `image.png`.

When I run this however I have two problems:

1. `image.png` is sought at the root directory
2. `image.png` is not in the webpack bundle

To get around this issue I have converted all images in `myNpmModule` to data URL's using the [webpack asset module](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#root) ("asset/inline"). This is an approach I've [copied from bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/f6694b74405261ed454d409ea5251f08cdf6c51c/scss/_variables.scss#L540) and it works. The problem is the file size of `app.jsx`, as it includes numerous 1MB+ images.

### Similar questions and issues I've found

- [What is the best way to distribute static assets via NPM package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66940621/what-is-the-best-way-to-distribute-static-assets-via-npm-package)

The question is tied to scss processing, rather than the inclusion of images in `.js` files. I've read the [resolve modules documentation for webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules) I couldn't see a way to tie it to a solution.

- [Include assets from webpack bundled npm package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559850/include-assets-from-webpack-bundled-npm-package)

This effectively copies the assets from `node_modules/myNpmModule/dist/assets` to your build directory, which is hacky. From what I can tell I'd need to modify `myNpmModule` to only ever look for assets in that destination directory which doesn't scale.

- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7353 , https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/12719

Recommends you use `new URL('./image.png', import.url.meta)` to import the images. That doesn't work - or at least the images aren't bundled by the webpack process for `project/app.jsx`

### My questions

One approach I've thought of is to configure webpack to convert data URL's into files during the webpack build process. The view is that these would then be pushed to the build directory.

1. is there a webpack loader to convert data URL's into files?
2. is there a better approach?

Unfortunately none of these give satisfactory answers for 3rd parties that will be installing my `myNpmModule`.

Comment: I tend to always use something like Webpack copy plugin that just copies a static assets folder to the dist folder so I can just use images as normal when developing the app and then just move these assets to a static server when publishing the app. I'll configure the host of the static as a `env` variable and then just swap it to the CDN hostname instead of localhost when built with production. Encoded images make bundles heavy so you'll need to learn code splitting (https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) to get around that.

Comment: that can work for your own code. But if a third party is installing `myNpmModule` as a dependency it doesn't really as it requires they copy the content from `node_modules/myNpmModule/dist/assets`. It's not something I've seen done in other libraries as it's a bit messy... Also doesn't solve the problem of where `myNpmModule` code looks for assets I don't think

Comment: Which is why code splitting will work because the code will not be loaded at runtime and will only be loaded when needed which will get around the issue where your main app bundle is 1MB

Comment: So I gave it a go, and it does help. Unfortunately if I apply the chunking to `myNpmModule` it doesn't propagate up to the `project` itself. It looks like others are facing this issue too https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10722